# Can't handle selected option in a list

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Now I'm handling a Google Action entirely from webhook. 
I have this intent, called intent A where you can choose from a variety of options, and the selected option triggers the intent B. 
Since I wanted to make it look better, i decided to implement a list in the intent A. 
As soon as I implemented it i tested it both on my iphone and on the google assistant simulator: now the problem is that the list is showed all good and fine, but as soon as i tap one of the options, the response given me from the application is the equivalent of the input.unknown.

I will post some screenshots to make it clearer:

This is the first screen where i invoke my Assistant. It is in italian but basically it asks you to pick between one of the options.
[image]

Okay now let us suppose we pick the first One, Fiat. So we tap on it and we get this: 
('Non ho capito bene, potresti ripetere?' means 'I haven't understand what you said, could you please say it again?' and that's the default fallback intent speaking)
[image]

Looking at the request i see the query and the text value that are what they should be, but the intent B doesn't trigger anyway. So i try to type 'Fiat' on my own and the output is the following:
[image]

Thinking of what i see here the problem is with the 'rawtext' that isn't available when you tap on an option.

Here's how i implemented the list in javascript, if there's something missing it could be here, but i received no warning or error during upload or so.

```
app.intent('benvenuto', (conv) =>  {
 if(!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')){
 conv.add('<speak> Ciao! Sono il tuo Assistente FCA per l\'acquisto di 
 merchandise.' +
'<break time="500ms"/> Quale marchio ti interessa tra i seguenti? <break 
 time="1.5s"/>' +
'Fiat\n <break time="500ms"/> Jeep\n <break time="500ms"/> Alfa Romeo\n <break 
 time="500ms"/>' +
'Abarth\n <break time="500ms"/> Lancia <break time="500ms"/> </speak>');
} else {
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: '<speak> Ciao! Sono il tuo Assistente FCA per l\'acquisto di merchandise.' +
  '<break time="500ms"/> Quale marchio ti interessa tra i seguenti? </speak>',
  text: 'Ciao! Sono il tuo Assistente FCA per l\'acquisto di merchandise. Quale marchio ti interessa tra i seguenti?'
  }), new List({
  title: 'Marchi FCA',
  items: {
    'Fiat': {
      title: 'Fiat',
      description: 'Marchio storico da cui è nata FCA',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jusan-fca-124a6.appspot.com/o/loghi_colori%2Ffiat_col.png?alt=media&token=3a5f7322-3d17-45d6-8730-9e0894d4ed9a',
        alt: 'Fiat'
      }),
    },
    'Lancia': {
      title: 'Lancia',
      description: 'Marchio spesso associato a grande classe',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jusan-fca-124a6.appspot.com/o/loghi_colori%2Flancia_col.png?alt=media&token=82409980-811d-4783-b885-91803ee9a70c',
        alt: 'Lancia'
      }),
    },
    'Alfa Romeo': {
      title: 'Alfa Romeo',
      description: 'Marchio tipico che racchiude sportività ed eleganza',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jusan-fca-124a6.appspot.com/o/loghi_colori%2Falfa_col.png?alt=media&token=dff6fca1-4e4b-4acf-89a9-4c74bf8e6cb0',
        alt: 'Alfa Romeo'
      }),
    },
    'Abarth': {
      title: 'Abarth',
      description: 'Casa automobilistica che reinventa per una guida molto sportiva i modelli di punta di Fiat',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jusan-fca-124a6.appspot.com/o/loghi_colori%2Fabarth_col.png?alt=media&token=ca470e59-e9ad-4e2e-9f30-709032813133',
        alt: 'Abarth'
      }),
    },
    'Jeep': {
      title: 'Jeep',
      description: 'Uno tra i marchi più famosi al mondo per quanto riguarda SUV e fuoristrada.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jusan-fca-124a6.appspot.com/o/loghi_colori%2Fjeep.png?alt=media&token=f4e26167-6981-48d7-86fb-10cb276c3471',
        alt: 'Jeep'
      }),
    }
  }
}))
}

 })
```

Another thing that could be important is that when i try it on my iphone, if i tap another time on 'Fiat' instead of typing it, it works!

Now my question is, how can i manage to get to tap just one time and go ahead in the conversation without having to say/tap/type it again?

Comment: did you add "actions_intent_OPTION"  as an event in the intent which should be triggered after an option is selected?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi yes, as soon as I found it in the documentation, but with that event it comes out the prompt I set to come out when the parameter (fiat, lancia, etc) was missing

Comment: The option will be set by a previous intent, possibly using helpers - https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#helper_intents. When the user selects an option there must be an intent to catch the selected option. That intent should have this event.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi okay I’ll try this and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 intents - one to show the options to the user possibly by using [helpers](http://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#helper_intents) and second intent will have an event to catch the selected option by putting "`actions_intent_OPTION`" in the events section in the Dialogflow like 
[image]